# Fantasy Novel largely from the perspective of the cast of villains

Tags: story-identification, novel

This novel had the traditional hero's journey to take the item (special water) to the thing (evil gods sanctuary) and save the world(kill the evil god). It was written in such a way as to illustrate the goodness of the villains. Similar to "Villains by Necessity".

The evil god let the hero win, since he could not take the pain of existence any longer.

The Ork/Monster race that served the god was described as rock carvers (thats what the claws are for). Their general had a rock carving intended for his son.

The sanctuary of the evil god was filled with the disfigured outcasts of society. They served the evil god since he welcomed them and cared for them.

There where two other other evil generals. One was a mage/elf person who survived and fled. The other was a fat glutton who was amazing at logistics.

What is this novel's name? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the cover, title and/or time period?

Comment: I have a vague recollection of the cover being of the mountain fortes of the evil god.

My mind draws a blank on the title. 

Time period I read the book is within the last 10-15 years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like the [*The Sundering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sundering_%28series%29) duology by Jacqueline Carey, consisting of the novels *Banewreaker* and *Godslayer*.

It is only a series of two novels, but it is told from the point of view of the not-quite-so-evil side.  The bad guy is Satoris, and had been part of creation but was shunned after giving his gift to humanity (I believe it was basically sex and procreation).  His primary general was hunting a child-hero from a tribe destined to carry a massively dense source of water to quench a fire that protected the Godslayer, which was the only weapon that could kill Satoris.

There were several generals with their own backplots and personalities.  One plot involved trying to reinforce an ally through a magical passage underground, only to have the nominally "good side" wizard do the same thing at the same time and collapse everything dooming both armies.  In the end after kidnapping an elvish bride and basically letting her see his true self, Satoris effectively commits suicide by letting the chosen one succeed.  One of his generals escapes with a hidden power as a sequel hook, but to my knowledge Carey has no plans to revisit the setting.

Comment: Story stubs of this sound about right. Thank you greatly.

Comment: If it sounds right, we appreciate it if you would mark it as the answer :)